# Oracle Database Error Log

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I am running Oracle 11g on Windows 2008r2. This error pop up in SCOM:

```
Logfile Directory : D:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhomeOAM\diag\rdbms\oam\oam\trace 
Logfile name: D:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhomeOAM\diag\rdbms\oam\oam\trace\alert_oam.log 
String: ORA-20000: Unable to set values for table DBMS_TABCOMP_TEMP_CMP: does not exist or insufficient privileges
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see [here](https://anargodjaev.wordpress.com/2015/11/25/dbms_stats-gather_stats_job-encountered-errors-ora-20000-unable-to-set-values-for-table/) that it's nothing to worry about:

> This issue matches Bug 9939773 which was closed as not a bug as
> explained by the following description: "
>
> The compression advisor
> creates intermediate tables (creates/drops tables
> DBMS_TABCOMP_TEMP_UNCMP). In case a GATHER_STATS_JOB is run at the
> same time , the table(s) will be in the list of tables to be analyzed.
> In case the table is automatically dropped by the compression advisory
> job before the GATHER_STATS_JOB has reached to that table in the list,
> the ORA-2000 will be hit. When DBMS_STATS finds it is no longer
> available, it writes to the alert log.This is no different from the
> case where a user table is dropped during a statistics gather.  "

Answer (score 1):

Table compression creates an intermediate table DBMS_TABCOMP_TEMP_CMP while it's running. If stats gathering is running at the same time, you can get this error. The job tried to gather stats on a table that has been dropped. You can safely ignore this error.